# Trying to get my Bot to detect an Inavlid Command

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to get my bot to detect when a command is not valid (in the list) and return a message saying to the user that it's inavalid, I've tried a heap of methods and It keeps saying the Invalid Command message for Every message, even the Valid commands.

```js
    if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}`)) {
        let commands = ["help", "mod", "ping", "serverinfo", "8ball", "suggest", "coinflip", "botinfo", "avatar", "info", "serverlogo", "ssu", "close"];

        if (!message.content.includes(commands)) {
            return message.channel.send(`Sorry it looks like you have entered an invalid command, Please use ${prefix}help to get a list of useable commands`)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the prefix from the message.content and you are checking in the wrong way:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}`)) {
    let commands = ["help", "mod", "ping", "serverinfo", "8ball", "suggest", "coinflip", "botinfo", "avatar", "info", "serverlogo", "ssu", "close"];

    const command = message.content.replace(prefix, "");
    if (!commands.includes(command)) {
        return message.channel.send(`Sorry it looks like you have entered an invalid command, Please use ${prefix}help to get a list of useable commands`)
    }
}
```

Comment: This Worked for me, Thanks,
I just to add a "!" in the second if statement

" if (commands.includes(command)) { "

Comment: I believe that my answer is better since this will not work when you have arguments after the command, such as (! is the prefix in this example) `!8ball Should I dance?` will return an invalid command error with this answer

Comment: @Samathingamajig Most of my commands use a return argument after sedning the last message, so for me adding the "!" is fine becuase the code returns before it as the Validity test is at the bottom of my code. But for others I see what you mean

Comment: What I'm saying is, with the previous example, is that this solution looks to see if `"8ball Should I dance?"` is in the `commands` array, while mine checks if the first word, `"8ball"` is in the `commands` array.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing the wrong way around. You should be testing if the array includes the message string, not if the message string includes the array.

```js
if (!commands.includes(message.content)) { // This doesn't work exactly
```

Another thing you need to do is remove the prefix from the message content and every subsequent argument.

```js
if (!commands.includes(message.content.replace(prefix, "").split(' ')[0])) { // This first removes the first instance of the prefix, then gets the first argument, which is the command
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, However I htink it might be becuase I am still on v11.6.4 of the Discord.js API

Comment: @HellBoundDeadman This didn't work because I accidentally forgot a `)`, it should work now.